# Windows Phone AppResources image

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a file called AppResources.resx in my project and I am able to put strings in there for localization purposes.  I can then access them via binding as such;

```
Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.MyString, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}
```

You are also able to add images to this resource file, but I cannot figure out how to bind to the images I put in there!  Is there a way?  Should I not be putting images in this file?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an image brush in ResourceDictionary:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="MyImageBrush" ImageSource="/Img-1.jpg"/>
```

And you can call it to set as a background, or as a Fill for rectangle:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="ImageForeground" Height="100" Width="100" 
    Fill="{StaticResource MyImageBrush}" />
```

Other option is to use a special converter, like it is described [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-imagebrush-binding-problem-workaround).

This ways are suitable for images wich are not localizable.

If you want to set different images for different cultures, you can try [this way](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2009/07/14/silverlight-quick-tip-resx-image-resources.aspx). Not sure if it works for windows phone, but it works for Silverlight.